# Can drupal do this?

Tags: drupal, web

I am a php developer using mostly CakePHP, magento, and wordpress. I want to create a community driven website aimed at the volunteering community that will let users sign up, create profiles, add previous voluntary positions, let organisations sign up and post jobs, etc. Is this something that drupal can handle? Is this what drupal was built to do?

I'm just wondering how drupal deals with custom methods. Say I wanted to have a user request a reference from someone, I'd have to write methods that did this. Would that be possible in drupal?

I'd love to hear from anyone doing something similar!

Thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is exactly the same as Jeremy... I have never done a project that has not benefited from drupal and its highly extendible nature.

It sounds like your project is quite large and is going to require a fair few modules to get going. I would have an extensive google for the different spec points you need to meet (for example: "drupal user profile module") and be sure to look at the related modules down the side.

> I'm just wondering how drupal deals
>   with custom methods. Say I wanted to
>   have a user request a reference from
>   someone, I'd have to write methods
>   that did this. Would that be possible
>   in drupal?in drupal?

Drupal provides hooks which allow you to interact with most aspects of it. Custom functionality goes into modules and pretty much everything you will deal with is a module.

Lastly I can't find any examples, but I know that projects like yours have successfully been done using drupal!

Comment: thanks hookd, since I posted this question I've gotten as far + more than I had after spending a couple of days on it with CakePHP. Also the content construction kit for content types is a life saver!

Answer (score 3):

> Can Drupal do this?

Yes.

You may want to take a look at [drupal commons](http://acquia.com/products-services/drupal-commons)  a distribution of drupal with a lot of community features built in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

**And If you are going to use the drupal 7 then it can be done very easily. You just have to manage some fields and just to assign a proper permissions to the users.**

Answer (score 0):

These tasks can be done with drupal. There are already module exists for User Profile, User Relationships, Groups etc. All post can be handled as node concept. User registration, user sign up all are available at the installation of Drupal. And it is extensible.

Thanks
-Rinku